# Can genstrings work on custom #defines?

Tags: ios, localization, genstrings

The macros iOS has for creating localized strings are pretty awesome when used with `genstrings`.  However, I'd like to create my own #define on top of one of the macros like so:

```
#define MyLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(key, tbl, val, comment) \
NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(key, tbl, [NSBundle mainBundle], val, comment)
#endif
```

Essentially, I always want to be going against the main bundle, so I don't feel the need to type it out every time.  This works great in code, but `genstrings` doesn't pick up my macro.  Is there anything I can do to make it pick up my custom macro?  I saw on the man page that there's a routine parameter that looks like what I'm trying to do, but I was unable to get it to work.

Answer (score 4):

Type `genstrings` to see the help text. Notice the `-s substring` option. You want something like:

```
genstrings -s MyLocalizedString -o someDir *.m
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that.  The command I'm running is

`genstrings *.m -s MyLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue`

but it's not picking up the macro

Comment: That's the wrong value. Look at what I showed compared to what you are using for the `-s` option.

Comment: I'm still confused.  Are you saying I should be using `MyLocalizedString` instead of `MyLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue`?  That wouldn't make sense, as my macro is called `MyLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue`.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying. Run the `genstrings` command with no arguments and look at what it says for the `-s` argument. It expects the prefix to use instead of `NSLocalizedString`.

Comment: OK, I understand what you're saying now.  I didn't see anything in the man page that made me think it was a prefix.

It's still not working though.  The output of genstrings is complaining that anything I pass through `MyLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue` is not a literal string and therefore not adding it to my strings file.  Any idea why?

Comment: I don't know. Suggestion - instead of using your `MyLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue` macro, why not do `#define MB [NSBundle mainBundle]`. Then you can do `NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(@"some.key", @"sometbl", MB, @"some val", @"some comment");`

Comment: I'm looking to remove the `bundle` and eventually `table` parameters altogether.  The rest of my team is going to start hammering on this in a month or two, and the more I can prevent them from going away from the standard the better.

Comment: Heh. This is a crazy bit of customisation. It's like, "You can have it in any colour, as long as its black."